# Python indentation error between two text-editors

Tags: python, indentation

I have a weird problem right now in python3.

I have a script with the correct indentation, but when I compile it says I have inconsistent use of tabs or spaces.

I'm using geany, so in geany it is correct indentation, but when I open the file in vim it's all wrong. But when I fix the problem in vim it's all wrong in geany and the compiler will tell me whats wrong (in geany). So either way I'm stuck now.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you try replacing tabs with spaces? Under Documents press replace tabs with spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have faced similiar problems when using notepad++ editor, When I am doing editing using notepad++ I have faced same kind of identation error.

I have replaced every tabs with 5 spaces & I am able to solve identation error in my script.

I hope doing same work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll try it soon!

Answer (score 3):

Use another editor such as sublime text, VSCode or PyCharm which has a feature for replacing tabs with spaces (or the other way around), this sould fix your problem.

You can also stick with vim and run the following command inside vim:

`:retab`

Comment: Thanks, ill try it out.